# How to use Gradle liquibaseRuntime configuration in a Kotlin/Multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, liquibase, kotlin-multiplatform

Currently, I'm porting my Spring Boot `build.gradle.kts` configuration to the Kotlin/MP stack. I don't know what to do with one part of the `liquibaseRuntime` configuration. The original config looks like:

```
// other dependencies omitted  
liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8")
liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").compileClasspath)
liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").output)
liquibaseRuntime("org.postgresql:postgresql")
liquibaseRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:$springBootVersion")
```

Some part of this config possibly can be replaced with:

```
sourceSets {
    val jvmMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            configurations["liquibaseRuntime"].dependencies.addAll(listOf(
                DefaultExternalModuleDependency("org.liquibase", "liquibase-core", null, "default"),
                DefaultExternalModuleDependency("org.liquibase.ext", "liquibase-hibernate5", "3.8", "default"),
                DefaultExternalModuleDependency("org.postgresql", "postgresql", null, "default"),
                DefaultExternalModuleDependency("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot", "2.2.4.RELEASE", "default")
    //          DefaultSelfResolvingDependency(configurations["compileClasspath"])
            ))
```

I've got stuck with these two and don't know what to do:

```
liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").compileClasspath)
liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").output)
```

They add instances of the dependency class `DefaultSelfResolvingDependency` (they also seem to be wrapped with some proxy). Looking through the liquibase-gradle plugin code didn't help.

So, how should I port these two dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not familiar with with the Liquibase Gradle plugin. My assumption is you have applied the plugin in the following manner:

```
plugins {
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.2"
}
```

Then you *should* be able to do what you have normally:

```
dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:$springBootVersion")
}
```

If for some reason that didn't work out-of-the-box, then you need to help Gradle's Kotlin DSL by explicitly retrieving a reference of the `configuration`:

```
val liquibaseRuntime by configurations

dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8")
    liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").compileClasspath)
    liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").output)
    liquibaseRuntime("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:$springBootVersion")
}
```

You could also do the following as well:

```
dependencies {
    "liquibaseRuntime"("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    "liquibaseRuntime"("org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8")
    // ...
}
```

> Reference: [Understanding what to do when type-safe model accessors are not available](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_using_standard_api)

Now these two lines do not make sense to me.

```
liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").compileClasspath)
liquibaseRuntime(sourceSets.getByName("main").output)
```

According to the API documentation for [DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html), there are certain allowed notations. A `sourceSet` is not one of them. So not sure what to do there.

Comment: You are right. I can use the standard `dependencies` handler. Anyways, liquibase still fails to start but this issue is not related to the question. Thank you.